# Android connect to Wifi programmatically if wifi name match

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I would like to build an app, that checks all the available WiFi networks,

If a network's SSID matches a search key then connect to that network, if two networks match then connect to the one with the higher signal strength.

e.g. SearchKey = "Open";

here is the code to check check all the wifi names :

```
    if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                ArrayList<ScanResult> mItems = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
            List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            int size  = results.size();
            HashMap<String, Integer> signalStrength = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    ScanResult result = results.get(i);
                    if (!result.SSID.isEmpty()) {
                        String key = result.SSID + " " + result.capabilities;
                        Log.i("TAG", "ssid: " + result.SSID + " | level: " + result.level);
}
```

Then I would need to

```
Arrays.asList(mItems).contains("Open")
```

I am stuck here, How to do a proper check if the keyword "Open" exits, if so, then get the whole name and use below. ?

online sample how to conenct.

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", key);

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager).getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
//remember id
int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

UPDATE CODE ------------------------------  - --------------------------------- - -- ---------------------------------------

How to check, This works But Now I need to implement Search by signal strength

```
if (!result.SSID.isEmpty()) {
                        String key = result.SSID + " " + result.capabilities;
                        Log.i("TAG", "ssid: " + result.SSID + " | level: " + result.level);


                        if(result.SSID.contains("Open")) {
                            String useSSID = result.SSID;
                            Log.w(TAG, "useSSID => " + useSSID);

                            connectToWifi(MainActivity.this, useSSID);
                            break;
                        }
                        else { Log.e(TAG, "NO result  contains"); }
```

Now how can I query my :

```
ArrayList<ScanResult> mItems = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();


                if (!signalStrength.containsKey(key)) {
                    signalStrength.put(key, i);
                    mItems.add(result);
                } else {
                    int position = signalStrength.get(key);
                    ScanResult updateItem = mItems.get(position);
                    if (calculateSignalStength(wifiManager, updateItem.level) > calculateSignalStength(wifiManager, result.level)) {
                        mItems.set(position, updateItem);
                    }
                }


                     if(mItems.contains("Open")) {
                                String useSSID = mItems #how to the name SSID name from mItems ???
                                Log.w(TAG, "useSSID => " + useSSID);

                                connectToWifi(MainActivity.this, useSSID);
                                break;
                            }
                            else { Log.e(TAG, "NO result  contains"); }
```

=== **Now my question is how to the SSID name from mItems ?**
Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: `if(result.SSID.contains("Open"))` ?

Comment: I don't  get this part -  if (!result.SSID.isEmpty()) {

if(result.SSID.contains("Open")) {

useSSID = How to get the full SSID that contains"Open"

}

Comment: hiya, thanks for your help. I have update my question with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a snippet for the same:

```
public string getValidSSID()
{
    List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
    HashMap<String,ScanResult> distinctNetworks = new HashMap<String, ScanResult>();
    for(ScanResult scanResult :  results)
    {
        if(scanResult.SSID.contains("Open"))
        {
            if(!distinctNetworks.containsKey(scanResult))
            {
                distinctNetworks.put(scanResult.SSID, scanResult); 
            }
            else
            {
                if(WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(scanResult.level, distinctNetworks.get(scanResult.SSID).level)>0)
                {
                    distinctNetworks.put(scanResult.SSID, scanResult);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Set<String> networks  = distinctNetworks.keySet();// This will only contain one key which will be ths ssid with the max strength containing "open" in SSID
    for (String s : networks) {
        return s;
    }
}
```